# Get DbContext Instance used by asp.net boilerplate repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I started a new project using Aspnet Boiler plate, but  no longer feel like using repositories and tons of hidden engineering done behind the scene.

> Hence looking forward to get instance the db context instantiated by
>   Abp repositories framework and

1. work with Ef core LINQ queries directly.
2. Commit my changes directly using SaveChanges, rather than relying on
   abstracted transactions.

How do I fetch that instance please?

Comment: asp.net boilerplate (I presume that's what abp stands for) is a repository pattern used to abstract the used DbContext instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. work with Ef core LINQ queries directly.

You can get an instance of `DbContext` using `GetDbContext()` of `IDbContextProvider`.

```
private readonly YourDbContext _ctx;

public YourService(IDbContextProvider<YourDbContext> dbContextProvider)
{
    _ctx = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
}
```

> 2. Commit my changes directly using SaveChanges, rather than relying on abstracted transactions.

You can disable transactions by applying `[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]` attribute

[Here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#disabling-unit-of-work) is a relevant article on transaction management with ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Comment: You can get an instance of DbContext using GetDbContext() of IDbContextProvider

--> How did you get DbContext using GetDbContext() of IDbContextProvider? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: getting exception `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Arg_ParamName_Name'`

Answer (score 1):

@NitinSawant I had a similar issue, though in my case the parameter in question was specifically called out as `unitOfWork`. I had a database sweep-and-update seed helper class that was run from the `Postinitialize` method of a module:

```cs
public override void PostInitialize()
{
    // The hypothetical 'SweeperClass' in this example uses constructor
    // injection to obtain a IDbContextProvider instance and from there
    // get hold of a DbContext.
    //
    // As written, this code threw a null argument exception.

    var sweeperClass = IocManager.Resolve<SweeperClass>();
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

In this case, it was fortunately just a question of also resolving a unit of work to wrap the other object's construction.

```
using Abp.Domain.Uow;

public override void PostInitialize()
{
    using (IocManager.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>().Begin())
    {
        var sweeperClass = IocManager.Resolve<SweeperClass>();
        // ...do stuff...
    }
}
```

So @koryakinp's answer gave me most of the solution and I just needed the above adjustment to get things going for my particular use case.